# using mysql connector C++ with VS 2012

Tags: c++, mysql, visual-studio-2012

I have been trying to use mysql connector C++ with my application on Visual Studio 2012, I have followed the tutorial on mysql website step by step to statically link, I have added all the libraries and includes as mentioned in the tutorials, when I try to build the complete example they have I get 33 unresolved external symbol! all generated from mysqlcppconn-static.lib, one of them is as follow:

```
1>mysqlcppconn-static.lib(mysql_art_resultset.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external          symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __thiscall std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &)" (__imp_??0?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@QAE@ABV01@@Z)
```

anyone can assist me to resolve this issue, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Currently I have no VS2012 at hand. But did you add the needed include files and lib files from MySQL to your project settings?
As far as I remember it should be under project settings -> C/C++ -> General -> Additional Include Directories and the libs goto project settings -> linker -> general -> additional Library directories

Comment: yes actually I added all the necessary includes and libraries as mentioned in the tutorial, is the face that im developing a 32-bit application on a 64-bit operating system matters?

Comment: no, it doesen't matter if you develop a 32-bit app on a 64-bit system. But in VS you can chosse if you want to build a 32 or 64 bit application. Did you choose the right one and added also the 32/64bit libaries from MySQL to the coresponding settings?

Comment: yes I did, I know that the error is a library link one, but Im sure I have include them correctly,

Comment: I have an application which is working fine, I need to add to it a function that will take some data and store them in mysql database, so any solution for this I will be glad to apply, thank you